# How to mix tensorflow keras model and transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to import a pretrained model from Huggingface's transformers library and extend it with a few layers for classification using tensorflow keras. When I directly use transformers model (Method 1), the model trains well and reaches a validation accuracy of 0.93 after 1 epoch. However, when trying to use the model as a layer within a tf.keras model (Method 2), the model can't get above 0.32 accuracy. As far as I can tell based on the documentation, the two approaches should be equivalent. My goal is to get Method 2 working so that I can add more layers to it instead of directly using the logits produced by Huggingface's classifier head but I'm stuck at this stage.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from transformers import TFRobertaForSequenceClassification
```

Method 1:

```
model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base", num_labels=6)
```

Method 2:

```
input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,), dtype='int32')

attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, ), dtype='int32')

transformer = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base", num_labels=6)

encoded = transformer([input_ids, attention_mask])

logits = encoded[0]

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input_ids, attention_mask], outputs = logits)
```

Rest of the code for either method is identical,

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0),
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')])
```

I am using Tensorflow 2.3.0 and have tried with transformers versions 3.5.0 and 4.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here. I posted a bug report on HuggingFace GitHub and they fixed this in the new dev version (4.1.0.dev0 as of December 2020). The snippet below now works as expected:

```
input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,), dtype='int32')
attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, ), dtype='int32')

transformer = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base", num_labels=6)
encoded = transformer({"input_ids": input_ids, "attention_mask": attention_mask})
logits = encoded[0]
 
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = {"input_ids": input_ids, "attention_mask": attention_mask}, outputs = logits)
```

Comment: Hi @Deepdelusion! Why do we need the `encoded = transformer({"input_ids": input_ids, "attention_mask": attention_mask})` part? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ayalaall, OP @Deepdelusion creates a Keras functional API, and a functional API requires both the input and output dimensions to be mentioned. Hence, they are using `encoded` for obtaining the output/logits.